# How to specify options for Connection.sendTransaction() for VersionedTransaction?

Tags: send-transaction, versionedtransactions

I'm trying to specify skipPreflight in sendTransaction method the next way:

```
await connection.sendTransaction(transaction, {
        skipPreflight: true,
});
```

where transaction is VersionedTransaction.
According to @solana/web3.js [docs](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#sendTransaction), in versioned transaction case this function takes only 2 args, where the first is VersionedTransaction and the second are options.

However, looking at a [method realization code](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/a731d2df408ec71b53affbfba81d96dbea3b77e3/src/connection.ts#L5293), in case of versioned transaction sendTransaction method passes to sendRawTransaction "options" argument, which is the third and because is not defined (I passed only 2 args according to docs), rather than passing the second "signersOrOptions", which I specified to contain options.

So how to pass options to sendTransaction method in VersionedTransaction case?

Comment: I believe this is a bug, please file a PR making the change to properly pass `signersOrOptions` instead of `options` on that line.

Answer (score 1):

You can instead call `sendRawTransaction` directly.

```
await connection.sendRawTransaction(transaction.serialize(),
        { skipPreflight: true }
)
```

Of course, the fundamental solution to getting `sendTransaction` to work is to fix the bug (and send the PR fix) as mentioned in the comments section.